# Evaluate indefinite integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+ 1}{\sqrt{x}-1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can one evaluate the indefinite integral
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+ 1}{\sqrt{x}-1} \,dx$$

First I tried to multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1}$, but I couldn't get the final result. I also tried to seperate the integral into two $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1} dx + \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-1} dx$$

which failed to lead to a solution either. Is there another method that can be used?

Comment: What about the substitution $\sqrt x=t \Rightarrow x=t^2 \Rightarrow dx=2t\;dt$ ?

Comment: @MasterShifu I did it to, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way if you want to separate the fraction first, I would suggest writing it as $\frac{(\sqrt x-1)+2}{\sqrt x-1}=1+\frac2{\sqrt x-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The form of the denominator suggests the substitution $$t = \sqrt{x} - 1 .$$ In particular, $x$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $t$, so the substitution yields a rational integrand with denominator $t$.

Comment: You're right, it really works, thanks.

Comment: @Student you have to take special care when $0 > t$, since then, $\log(t)$ is undefined.  When $0 > t$, $\int \frac{dt}{t} = \int \frac{-dt}{-t} = - \log(-t).$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+ 1}{\sqrt{x}-1} \,dx\\
=& \int \frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt x(\sqrt{x}-1)} \,dx
 =\int \frac{(\sqrt{x}+2)(\sqrt x-1)+2}{\sqrt x(\sqrt{x}-1)} \,dx\\
 =& \int 1+\frac2{\sqrt x}+\frac{2}{\sqrt x(\sqrt{x}-1)} \,dx
=x +4\sqrt x+4\ln|\sqrt x-1|+C
\end{align}